# How can I get a transparent body background on SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I'm encountering a problem on Reporting Services, using BIDS (2008).

I need to create a report which has a transparent body background.
I mean, when I export it (TIFF or PNG, whatever), I need the whole background to be transparent.

When I edit my report, I check that the "Body" -> "BackgroundColor" is set to "No color" (putting "Transparent" as a value automatically brings it back to "No color").

But once my report is deployed and I generate it through the Reporting Services web interface, exporting it to TIFF format only gives me a report ... with a white background.

So here is my question : is it a well-known issue ? Is there a way to get my body background transparent ?
Maybe an easy way exists and I'm just missing it, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge this is not possible when exporting to Tiff / PNG. You could  however use a Batch background removal tool like ImageMagick;

http://www.imagemagick.org/

It is a command line tool, so a lot of automatizing / batch processing possibilities. It can be a bit intimidating at first but here is a easy tutorial addressing white background removal with imagemagick.

http://www.vectorns.com/blog/technical-articles/18-how-to-remove-white-background-from-a-picture

Comment: When you say that it's not possible when exporting to TIFF or PNG, do you mean that it can be possible exporting to another format ?

ImageMagick may be an alternative solution, but I'm not sure we could implement it in our specific context.
Anyway thanks, I'll keep that in mind !

But going back to BIDS / SSRS, it seems to me unbelievable that getting a transparent background is not possible through this tool.
One of my colleague told me he had read somewhere that it was possible  on VS 2005, but since 2008 it has become impossible.

If anyone has more information about this...